# Unable to connect react native app to backend on iOS 15

Tags: react-native, axios, fetch, info.plist, ios15

My react-native app is not able to connect to the backend on iOS 15 devices only.
Devices with iOS less than 15 and android devices are working fine.

I am using `http` connection with a static IP address.
I cannot switch to `https` now, neither can I use a domain name instead of an IP address. And I also cannot add the static IP to the exception domains since that is not accepted.

I have the following code in my `Info.plist` file:

```json
<dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Is there a way to fix this without using a domain name or switching to HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this, in case anyone came across this thread.
Weirdly, adding

```
'Accept-Language': 'en'
```

to the header when making the API calls solved this issue!

It is only happening on iOS 15 devices, so I don't know the reason, but it turned out to not be related to the HTTP connection.

Comment: Thank you very much, we had a similar problem and this saved our bacon! Out of curiosity: does your stack use `isomorphic-fetch`, either directly, or as a peer dependency of some other library? We're wondering if the problem might be specific to that library.